# show/hide polygons based on what the screen is showing

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I'm using google maps on my android app, loading multiple polygons to the map which causes a significant lag.
My map is pretty zoomed in, so many polygons aren't even shown on the screen (but still causing lag cause they are exist).

is there a way to only show polygons that are contained in the screen and hide the others? (polygons are shown or get hidden based on what the screen view)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get bounds for visible part, something like this:

```
LatLngBounds bounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
```

Then determine if your polygon is inside visible part bounds (by calling `bounds.contains(....)` for each polygon vertex). If not, just don't draw polygon.

Of course, you need to handle camera change events to recalculate visible bounds and draw missing polygons if needed (when their part of map become visible).